# XMLHttpRequest - Troubles with a cross domain API call

Tags: javascript, ajax

I need to do a *very* simple cross domain api call, and for reasons of overhead/compatibility,  dont want to use a fully-featured framework (such a jQuery), since this simple ajax request is pretty much all I need to do. I need to call do a `GET` request on `http://bar.com` from a page on `http://foo.com`. I cannot access the HTTP headers on `foo.com` however. I do not need to return data to the browser.

Currently doing the center code hereall results in (on Chrome):

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://bar.com/api?=x. 
Origin http://foo.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. 
http://bar.com/api?=x Failed to load resource
```

Incidentally, even though this call throws an error, it comes through fine on `bar.com`, so another option is basically just catching that error and ignoring it(?). Somewhat unfamiliar with JS though, so not sure if this will fail on other browsers?

Came across this: http://code.google.com/p/xmlhttprequest/source/browse/trunk/source/XMLHttpRequest.js - not sure if this is completely overkill for my use (overhead is pretty critical)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this will always fail unless you have set the [`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTTP_Access_Control) HTTP header to define specific domains which are allowed to be accessed via XHR.

One way you could work around this issue is by using script injection:

```
function load_script(loc) {
   var s = document.createElement('script');
   s.src = loc;
   document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);
}

load_script('http://bar.com/api?=x');
```

Comment: Thats the inexplicable thing; I'm loading the script by injection (as above). So I'm at a loss to explain why this is happening. At first I thought this may be because I was using jQuery (for testing), which was not hosted on bar.com. But even without this i am getting that access control error..